# How to print halftones for screenprint with AccuRIP

Tags: adobe-illustrator, screen-printing, color-separation

Basically our screen printing team can only print a max of 6 colours. Anything more than that needs halftones but I can't figure out how the old artist did it. It seems like AccuRIP automatically does the dots for the halftones but the actual file itself just has multiple colours.

The colours that are being turned into halftones though are assigned to the spot colours seemingly? This is what it looks like in the colour picker when I select one of the halftones[image]

The top colour is the spot colour and the bottom colour is the halftone and the actual colour of the object on screen. Does anyone know how to replicate this effect or what I should even look up to find a tutorial on this?

Comment: Your question lools interesting but it is not clear, especially your screen capture. It seems you cropped it or something. Please edit it to clarify. You can post several images.

Comment: Is the case that you want halftones, but you are not going to rent AccuRIP (= a high cost screen print mask making software) for it. You want a way to generate halftones from solid ones with the ordinary Adobe set or freeware? BTW Inkscape has a well working half tone generator which converts any image, for ex. a photo to an image which has the grayscale as  vector halftone patterns.